# How to restart System.Threading.Tasks.Task in C#

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task

I'm working on an application where i've a task that can be stopped & restarted later.
for that i've two methods:

```
public static void TaskProcess()
    {
        var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        CancellationToken token = tokenSource.Token;
        var task = new Task(
            () =>
                {
                    DoWork(token);
                }, 
            token);

        task.ContinueWith(
            task1 =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Task finished... press any key to continue");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    Console.WriteLine("Press q to quit...");
                },
            token);

        task.Start();

        string input;
        while ((input = Console.ReadLine()) != "q")
        {
            if (input == "c")
            {
                tokenSource.Cancel();
            }
            if (input == "r")
            {
                if (task.IsCompleted)
                {
                    // Here i want to restart my completed task
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Task is not completed");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static void DoWork(CancellationToken token)
    {
        int i = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            i++;
            Console.WriteLine("{0} Task continue...", i);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);

            if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Canceling");
                token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            }
        }
    }
```

Currently, i create new instance of Task and CancellationToken to "restart" the task but i'm looking for something better if possible:

```
if (input == "r")
            {
                if (task.IsCompleted)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Task is completed... Restarting");
                    tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
                    token = tokenSource.Token;
                    CancellationToken token1 = token;
                    task = new Task(
                        () => DoWork(token1),
                        token);
                    task.Start();
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Task is not completed");
                }
            }
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `Task` and `TaskCancellationSource` are use and throw objects. You can't reuse them. You'll have to create new objects as you're doing currently.

It makes sense, Assume you've cancelled a `Task`, later at some point some code needs to check the status of the `Task`. It came little later after you restarted the Task(not possible, saying for explanation), Won't that be misleading to tell status is `Running` for already `Canceled` Task ?

Comment: It's not enough for memory if i re-create new instances each time i want to restart?

Comment: @cYounes What makes you to think like that?

Comment: because this code will be in a service runs permanently and wanna be sure that it doesn't produce any error :)

Comment: @cYounes Don't worry, unless you store references to all the created objects Garbage collector will collect them.

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to restart a `System.Threading.Tasks.Task<TResult>`, I don't think you can: as the [Task Cancellation guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396(v=vs.110).aspx) says when a cancellation is invoked the task *must* terminate, and since the task has been terminated you can't restart it; so what you're doing is correct.

Or are you asking if there's a better pattern to handle this kind of workflow?

Comment: Exaclty, What i'm doing works correctly, but i worry about memory if i create new instances each time i restart the process

Comment: Why are you worrying about the used memory? Tasks gets allocated from the default thread pool (which has a fixed amount of available threads) when started and are released when terminated, so unless you're leaking objects or hanging tasks, you won't have memory issues. What you *can* have are overheads from starting a new task, but that's something only you can evaluate.